# Can an iPhone be a BLE peripheral?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

What I want to do is have my iPhone send advertising packets, just like a peripheral device would. Is this possible? Is there an app for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [*Core Bluetooth Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1):

> In this chapter, you learn how to use the Core Bluetooth framework to perform the most common types of Bluetooth low energy tasks from the peripheral side. The code-based examples that follow will assist you in developing your app to implement the peripheral role on your local device.

So: yes, it's possible.

There are probably apps that make your iPhone act like a peripheral, since the ability has been supported since iOS 6.0. But this is a site about programming, not app recommendations.